# i used the program SQL Fiddle and it keeps telling me that the table doesn't exist,what can i do to fix the two tables referencing each other?

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, foreign-keys

the Staff table references the branch table

```
CREATE TABLE Staff(
StaffNo VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
firstName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
lastName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
position VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
salary INTEGER
DEFAULT 3000,
CHECK (salary BETWEEN 3000 AND 25000),
email VARCHAR(25),
branchNo CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (StaffNo),
FOREIGN KEY (branchNo) REFERENCES Branch (branchNo));
```

and at the same time the branch table references the Staff table

```
create table Branch(
branchNo char(6) not null primary key,
street varchar(30) not null,
city varchar(20),
postCode char(5) not null,
ManagerNo varchar(5) not null,
foreign key (ManagerNo) references Staff(StaffNo));
```

Comment: . . Do you actually have a question?  It is also useful to tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your tables reference each other in the Foreign Keys you will get an error on either table creation if the other table has not been created yet. I would suggest that you remove the creation of the FOREIGN KEYs to separate ALTER TABLE statements:

```
CREATE TABLE Staff(
  StaffNo VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  firstName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  lastName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  position VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  salary INTEGER
  DEFAULT 3000,
  CHECK (salary BETWEEN 3000 AND 25000),
  email VARCHAR(25),
  branchNo CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (StaffNo)
);


create table Branch(
  branchNo char(6) not null primary key,
  street varchar(30) not null,
  city varchar(20),
  postCode char(5) not null,
  ManagerNo varchar(5) not null
); 

alter table staff
  add constraint fk1_branchNo foreign key (branchNo) references Branch (branchNo);

alter table branch
  add constraint fk1_ManagerNo foreign key (ManagerNo) references Staff (StaffNo);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/180fa)

Comment: does it work with oracl 11g ? because i keep getting "invalid identifier" @bluefeet

Answer (score 1):

You can remove one reference from one table and keep the other.then you can retrieve data using the remainig reference.Is there any problem with that?

Comment: is that the only way it can be fixed? because i was going to do that but then i'll have to fix the schema and i'm not allowed to do that

Comment: I think it is the only way to remove the refering each other.But I don't understand why it is not allowing to keep both foreign keys as it is.If you want to keep bidirectional relationship then you have to keep both of them.